# android Saving Data as Key-Value Sets

Tags: javascript, java, android, sharedpreferences, textview

Good evening, I am creating an application and I need help with this error.
the

```
log cat of the error:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at cqdevelopers.incrediblediet.Fragment3.getAddressKeyValueFile(Fragment3.java:90)
                                                                               at cqdevelopers.incrediblediet.Fragment3.onCreateView(Fragment3.java:25)



<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    05-16 02:25:21.711 6498-6498/cqdevelopers.incrediblediet E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: cqdevelopers.incrediblediet, PID: 6498
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at cqdevelopers.incrediblediet.Fragment3.getAddressKeyValueFile(Fragment3.java:90)
                                                                                   at cqdevelopers.incrediblediet.Fragment3.onCreateView(Fragment3.java:25)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:254)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.completeScroll(ViewPager.java:1920)
                                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:2050)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2108)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2553)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2403)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1737)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2765)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2364)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9514)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
                                                                                at android.view.
```

Fragment3.java:

```
public class Fragment3 extends Fragment {
    private EditText editText;
    private TextView textView;
    private Button button;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment3_layout, container, false);

        getAddressKeyValueFile();
        editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.tvadress);
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String address = null;

                address = editText.getText().toString();
                textView.setText(address);

                setAddressKeyValueFile(address);

            }
        });


        return v;
    }


    private void getAddressKeyValue() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("r", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String key = getString(R.string.address);
        String existingAddress = sharedPreferences.getString(key, null);

        if (existingAddress != null) {

            TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText(existingAddress);

        }


    }

    private void setAddressKeyValue(String address)
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("d" ,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        String key = getString(R.string.address);
        editor.putString(key,address);

        editor.commit();


    }

    private void getAddressKeyValueFile()
    {
        Context context = getContext().getApplicationContext();

        String fileName = getString(R.string.filename);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(fileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String key = getString(R.string.address);
        String existingAddress = sharedPreferences.getString(key,null);

        if(existingAddress != null)
        {
            TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText(existingAddress);
        }

    }


    private void setAddressKeyValueFile(String address)
    {
        Context context = getContext().getApplicationContext();
        String fileName = getString(R.string.filename);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(fileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        String key = getString(R.string.address);
        editor.putString(key, address);

        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

And fragment3.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="cqdevelopers.incrediblediet.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tvadress"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="register"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvadress"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Kindly have a look on exception and let me know where i am doing wrong, your help is appreciated thanks in Advance.

Comment: Here:  `TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);` line causing issue. pass `v` as parameter to `getAddressKeyValueFile ` method and do it as `TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);`

Answer (score 0):

change position of getAddressKeyValueFile

```
//getAddressKeyValueFile();
editText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.tvadress);
textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
getAddressKeyValueFile();
```

and delete line:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

in getAddressKeyValueFile()

Answer (score 0):

This line of code `textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);` is trying to get the `TexView` with the id `textView` from the activity's layout not from the fragment's layout.

You should change:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(existingAddress);
```

to:

```
if(textView!=null){
    textView.setText(existingAddress);
}
```

in both the `getAddressKeyValueFile()` and `getAddressKeyValue()` methods.

Also, in the `onCreateView(...)` method, call `getAddressKeyValueFile();` only after `textView` has been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

in the getAddressValueFile, change the way the strings are retrived.

```
private void getAddressKeyValueFile()
    {
        Context context = getContext().getApplicationContext();

        String fileName = getResources.getString(R.string.filename);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(fileName,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String key = getResources.getString(R.string.address);
        String existingAddress = sharedPreferences.getString(key,null);

        if(existingAddress != null)
        {
            TextView textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText(existingAddress);
        }

    }
```

instead of

```
getString(R.string.filename)
```

change to

```
getResources.getString(R.string.filename)
```

Also, make similar changes in the setAddressKeyValue method.